# Reduce UserDefaults Integer Value - Swift

Tags: swift, userdefaults

Is there any way to reduce the UserDefaults integer key value?

This is my code to save it:

```
    var highScore = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE")
```

How could reduce this value by a fixed integer?

So reduce by 20 etc?

Comment: Are you asking how to subtract a number from a variable? And then how to store that updated value back into UserDefaults? That's some very simply stuff. Is this actually your question?

Comment: I know how to do this however I wasn't sure if it was the same with a userDefault value?

Comment: Why didn't you try it before posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, obtain the old value of the high score. Then, do the arithmetic before finally saving the new value:

```
let oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE")
let newValue = oldValue - 20

UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "HIGHSCORE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var highScore: Int {
  get {
     return Userdefaults.standard.integer(forKey: “highScore”)
   } set {
Userdefaults.standard.set(newValue forKey: “highScore”)
   }
}
```

Can set high score by

> ```
> highScore = 5
> ```